# How to setup a web server with remote SMTP

Tags: iis-7, smtp, email

I have 2 severs, both running server 2008 (R2)

One is the web server, one is running as a mail server.

The setup I want is that any mail sent from apps (php, asp and asp.net) on the web server are sending mail through the mail server's SMTP server...but this seems to be proving trickier than i'd hoped.

The mail server is running MailEnable, and the web server IIS7 (maybe 7.5)

What i don't want is to setup an open relay SMTP server on the web server, as this is going to be open to abuse (even if I just allow relay from local address).

the problem is, there doesn't appear to be a way to specify credentials in php so if I point it at the mail server, then the mail server has to be set as an open relay, which is almost worse.

Any ideas how I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to look to set up is SMTP-AUTH.  We do exactly what you're looking to achieve by creating what we call "proxy accounts" which are nothing more than dummy accounts to satisfy the SMTP-AUTH requirement while protecting the SMTP server from becoming an open relay.

Here is some PHP that describes how to specify an SMTP-AUTH connection:
http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

From the Mail server product web site, I do not see SMTP-AUTH mentioned but I see how to setup MailEnable for smtp-auth here:

http://www.mailenable.com/kb/content/view.asp?ID=ME020335